# can't display 640x1136 image on iphone5

Tags: ios, retina-display, iphone-5

I've added a Default-568h@2x.png launch image to my app. The app needs to display a *second* launch image after the "real" launch image. Because the UIImage imageNamed: method doesn't automatically load the taller image the way it automatically loads retina images, I've added some code to detect the screen size and display the correct image:

```
-(void)pickRightImage
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    UIImageView *imgv = [self loadingImage];

    UIImage *img;

    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading_screen.png"];
    } else if([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && result.height == 568) {
        // iPhone 5
       img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading_screen-568h@2x.png"];       
    }
    [imgv setImage:img];
}
```

The imageView takes up the whole screen in the NIB, which is named MainWindow, and I have selected the checkbox named "Full Screen At Launch" However, the image never takes up the whole screen. (Although the launch image does.) The second image is letter boxed just as if it were a smaller image, and I had never included the tall launch image.

Is there anyway to programmatically display a full screen image on the 4 inch iphone5? Why is my image always resized?

Comment: i don't know if it will help but when you do your checks for the height - use 480.0f and 568.0f instead of just integer values. Also see this link - this is what I'm using without any problems: http://odoruinu.net/blog/2012/09/26/automatically-loading-iphone-5-sized-images-where-required/

Comment: please add breakpoint to check if your code get executed or not.

Comment: Kaan's probably hit the nail on the head; floating point precision is probably doing it for you. Have you tried adding a log or a breakpoint to see which path your code follows?

Comment: I have stepped through the code, and on the iphone5 it does follow the 568 path. (Although that's a good suggestion to add the ".0f" in any case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on the main view controller. Also, on Target > Summary > Status Bar > Visibility check "Hide during application launch".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Second-default568h@2x.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
}
```

Comment: didn't know about the status bar option. Its still scaling incorrectly, so I might have something else wrong too.

Comment: Thanks for this! The secret turned out to be addSubview. Just displaying a UIImage in the MainWindow will never be scaled properly.

Answer (score 4):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` will take care of adding the `@2x` for you. So you should just specify

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading_screen-568h.png"];
```

It's also useless to test both a 4" screen AND the Retina criteria (scale = 2). All devices that have a 4" screen (568px tall) are Retina displays, so you can assume that if height == 568, the user has an iPhone 5 : replace

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && result.height == 568)
```

with

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

and you're good.

Comment: thanks that worked. i had an issue where i was adding @2x at the end of the image name and it ended up zooming in 2x